# active record all query from instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Maybe somebody has an idea how I could solve following problem:

I have a Model and want to query it.

```
def MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  # instance method
  def all
    my_models = MyModel.all
    my_models.?? # order my_models ActiveRecord::Relation, that the instance which calls the .all instance method is at first position, and the rest is sorted somehow,..whatever.
  end

end
```

How could I solve that?

**EDIT:**

Example:
MyModel has a name.
I have four instances of MyModel

```
MyModel.all => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<MyModel id: 1, name: "name1">, #<MyModel id: 2, name: "name2">, #<MyModel id: 3, name: "name3">, #<MyModel id: 4, name: "name4">]>
```

And I want now:

```
MyModel.find(1).all => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<MyModel id: 1, name: "name1">, #<MyModel id: 2, name: "name2">, #<MyModel id: 3, name: "name3">, #<MyModel id: 4, name: "name4">]>

MyModel.find(2).all => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<MyModel id: 2, name: "name2">, #<MyModel id: 1, name: "name1">, #<MyModel id: 3, name: "name3">, #<MyModel id: 4, name: "name4">]>

MyModel.find(3).all => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<MyModel id: 3, name: "name3">, #<MyModel id: 1, name: "name1">, #<MyModel id: 2, name: "name2">, #<MyModel id: 4, name: "name4">]>
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to accomplish with my_model.

Comment: I added an example :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this accomplishes what you're asking.

```
def all
  self.class.order("case when id = #{id} then 0 else id end")
end
```

Comment: Nearly yes, but there is a little error.. MyModel.find(2).all.map(&:id) => [2,3,4]. 1 is missing. MyModel.find(1).all.map(&:id) => [1], 2,3 and 4 are missing..

Comment: I can't recreate that locally. I get the same result set regardless of the id passed to `.find`, as expected. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite3. Other facts: rails 4.0.0, ruby 2.0.0-p195

Comment: Ok sorry, was my fault. I use STI and with self.class I only got 3 records, because of the class :). With calling directly: MyModel.order("case when id = #{id} then 0 else id end") everything works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be taking advantage of the fact that an ActiveRecord::Relation instance responds to many of the Array instance methods:

```
def all
  ary = self.class.order(:id)
  ary = ary.unshift(self)
  ary.uniq
end
```

However this returns an instance of Array so you can't keep appending additional scopes. Up to you to decide whether that's acceptable in your case.

Comment: Thanks! Also works, but I think @Deefour´s answer is more convenient. But thanks anyway.

Comment: This also doesn't return an ActiveRecord::Relation instance.

Comment: I am aware of that, and my answer states this returns an instance of Array so nobody was misled, but thank you.